# How to catch a resource assembly not found exception under .net framework 4?

Tags: asp.net, .net, .net-4.0, assemblies

I recently switched a DotNetNuke 6 install to a .net 4 framework, and i've started getting the following error:

```
DotNetNuke.Services.Exceptions.PageLoadException: Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation. ---> System.Reflection.TargetInvocationException: Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation. ---> System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not find file 'Telerik.Web.UI.resources'. 
at System.Reflection.RuntimeAssembly.InternalGetSatelliteAssembly(String name, CultureInfo culture, Version version, Boolean throwOnFileNotFound, StackCrawlMark& stackMark) 
at System.Resources.ManifestBasedResourceGroveler.GetSatelliteAssembly(CultureInfo lookForCulture, StackCrawlMark& stackMark) 
at System.Resources.ManifestBasedResourceGroveler.GrovelForResourceSet(CultureInfo culture, Dictionary`2 localResourceSets, Boolean tryParents, Boolean createIfNotExists, StackCrawlMark& stackMark) 
at System.Resources.ResourceManager.InternalGetResourceSet(CultureInfo requestedCulture, Boolean createIfNotExists, Boolean tryParents, StackCrawlMark& stackMark) 
at System.Resources.ResourceManager.InternalGetResourceSet(CultureInfo culture, Boolean createIfNotExists, Boolean tryParents) 
at System.Resources.ResourceManager.GetString(String name, CultureInfo culture) 
at Telerik.Web.LocalizationProvider.EmbeddedResourceLocator.GetString(String resourceKey) 
at Telerik.Web.LocalizationStrings.GetString(String key, Boolean throwErrorIfMissing) 
at Telerik.Web.LocalizationStrings.GetString(String key) 
at Telerik.Web.UI.ComboBoxStrings.get_AllItemsCheckedString() --- End of inner exception stack trace --- 
at System.RuntimeMethodHandle.InvokeMethod(Object target, Object[] arguments, Signature sig, Boolean constructor) 
at System.Reflection.RuntimeMethodInfo.UnsafeInvokeInternal(Object obj, Object[] parameters, Object[] arguments) 
at System.Reflection.RuntimeMethodInfo.Invoke(Object obj, BindingFlags invokeAttr, Binder binder, Object[] parameters, CultureInfo culture) 
at System.Web.SecurityUtils.MethodInfoInvoke(MethodInfo method, Object target, Object[] args) 
at System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptSerializer.SerializeCustomObject(Object o, StringBuilder sb, Int32 depth, Hashtable objectsInUse, SerializationFormat serializationFormat) 
at System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptSerializer.SerializeValueInternal(Object o, StringBuilder sb, Int32 depth, Hashtable objectsInUse, SerializationFormat serializationFormat, MemberInfo currentMember) 
at System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptSerializer.SerializeValue(Object o, StringBuilder sb, Int32 depth, Hashtable objectsInUse, SerializationFormat serializationFormat, MemberInfo currentMember) 
at System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptSerializer.Serialize(Object obj, StringBuilder output, SerializationFormat serializationFormat) 
at System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptSerializer.Serialize(Object obj, SerializationFormat serializationFormat) 
at Telerik.Web.UI.RadComboBox.DescribeComponent(IScriptDescriptor descriptor) 
at Telerik.Web.UI.RadDataBoundControl.Telerik.Web.IControl.DescribeComponent(IScriptDescriptor descriptor) 
at Telerik.Web.UI.ScriptRegistrar.GetScriptDescriptors(Control control) 
at Telerik.Web.UI.RadDataBoundControl.GetScriptDescriptors() 
at Telerik.Web.UI.RadDataBoundControl.System.Web.UI.IScriptControl.GetScriptDescriptors() 
at System.Web.UI.ScriptControlManager.RegisterScriptDescriptors(IScriptControl scriptControl) 
at Telerik.Web.UI.RadDataBoundControl.RegisterScriptDescriptors() 
at Telerik.Web.UI.RadDataBoundControl.Render(HtmlTextWriter writer) 
at System.Web.UI.Control.RenderControlInternal(HtmlTextWriter writer, ControlAdapter adapter) 
at System.Web.UI.Control.RenderControl(HtmlTextWriter writer, ControlAdapter adapter) 
at System.Web.UI.Control.RenderControl <....snip, rendering call stack>
```

I have no idea why this error happens since i can't reproduce it on another server, or even on the same server. Since i don't find a solution i'm trying to patch it so i looked at the workaround proposed in this post:
http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/32e458a1-7443-4309-a054-8839b33dfd4f/framework-40-dll-loaded-by-a-20-executable-cannot-find-xxxxresourcesdll

So the workaround would be to

> catch the FileNotFoundException in HostRuntime.ResolveAssembly and return null. This should prevent the process from crashing.

I can add some code to the application through a HttpModule, but i really don't see how i'm supposed to patch the HostRuntime.ResolveAssembly... any idea?

---

Edit: I've been diggin in the mscorlib assembly for the framework 4 and i see something very weird:

The call from the ManifestBasedResourceGroveler to the SatelliteAssembly loading is the following:

```
try
    {
        runtimeAssembly = this._mediator.MainAssembly.InternalGetSatelliteAssembly(satelliteAssemblyName, lookForCulture, this._mediator.SatelliteContractVersion, false, ref stackMark);
    }
    catch (FileLoadException ex)
    {
        int hResult = ex._HResult;
        Win32Native.MakeHRFromErrorCode(5);
    }
    catch (BadImageFormatException)
    {
    }
```

So it catches exceptions, but here is the code for `InternalGetSatelliteAssembly`

```
if (runtimeAssembly == this)
    {
        throw new FileNotFoundException(string.Format(culture, Environment.GetResourceString("IO.FileNotFound_FileName"), new object[]
        {
            assemblyName.Name
        }));
    }
```

Ok, so i will always get a FileNotFoundException that won't be caught... that looks like a really weird behavior to me

Answer (score 0):

Based on the stack trace it looks like a Telerik version issue.  Are you sure that the proper assemblies are all loaded?

Comment: I'm pretty sure, i add a look at the fusion logs and didn't see any weird version numbers. Is there a way i can make ultra sure the versions loaded are the correct ones?

Comment: I checked again our fusion logs and i'm positive that all versions match the framework 4 and are matched in version numbers